# Possible if want to do API Load Testing using JMeter with URI info only?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing, jmeter-4.0

My team planned to do API Performance Testing using JMeter 5.0 for my client. My client developed the API in Kubernetes. Just wondering, they gave info such as URI, HTTP Method and Content-Type only. We never have experience using URI. Are these info sufficient to do load test in JMeter? And where do I fill in these info? Is it in Config Element: HTTP Header Manager?

Because usually I only do my enablement using sample website which already provide the URL.

[image]

Do I need to ask them to provide the specific URL for this? Or URL can be extracted from URI?

Thanks.

Comment: can please also share the example uri which type of uri you got from the client so other can get idea, however, it's hard guessing how they have exposed their services to publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should put:

1. Protocol, server name or IP and Port Number into [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults), this way you will have a single configuration element having these details and in case of change you will need to introduce the change at one place only and won't have to revisit each and every HTTP Request sampler
2. Individual requests are defined using individual HTTP Request samplers where you need to provide URL [Path](https://zvelo.com/anatomy-of-full-path-url-hostname-protocol-path-more/#pathfile) and request body (if any)
3. [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and other [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) can be provided via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), the same [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) as for HTTP Request Defaults apply, for example if you want to send `application/json` for all the requests just add HTTP Header Manager on the top of your Test Plan and it will add the header to all HTTP Request samplers which are at the same level as the HTTP Header Manager or lower.

Comment: thanks sir. one question, if we already include the body data during the `post` request, do we cannot click on the parameters in HTTP Request section?

Comment: Yep, either parameters or body data.